# Showing form errors on a dropdown form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation, error-handling

my title might sound strange so I'll try to explain it better in here.

I have a login form that is hidden when you visit the page. It's located in the upper right corner as a small dropdown form. This is the code without the Jquery since I think it isn't needed for my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include "core/init.php";

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Swimstats</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="border"></div>
            <div id="login">
                <div id="userName" class="toggleOff">
                    <?php
                    if(logged_in() === true){
                         echo '<p>Welcome ' . $_SESSION['userID'] . '</p>';
                    } else {
                    ?>
                    <p>Have an account? <span id="test">Sign in here!</span></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div id="login-content">
                    <form class="clearfix" action="checkuser.php" method="post">
                        <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />

                        <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

SO a simple dropdown form, but I whenever the user fills in faulty credentials or leaves something empty or whatever I need to show an error under the form or above, doesn't matter. I have the following code to catch the errors:

```
<?php

include "core/init.php";

    if(empty($_POST) === false){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true){
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter your email and password.';
    } else if(user_exists($email) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Unable to find that email.';
    } else {
        $login = login($email, $password);
        if($login === false){
            $errors[] = 'Email/password combination is incorrect!';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $login;
                header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    }

?>
```

But this method will just bring me to the checkuser.php page and show me the errors there while I have to get the errors show on the form, but I seriously have no clue how to get that.

Comment: You're using sessions. I see no mention of `session_start();` anywhere. That's likely your problem. `session_start();` needs to be at the top of every page. Insert `session_start();` at the top of every page, try that and give me your results.

Comment: FYI: You have `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of `PHP`. Put that over top of your `<html>`. Won't solve your problem but it's just good practice. You don't want output before PHP.

Comment: My session_start() is located in core/init.php so that shouldn't cause any problems. But I have no idea where of how to print the errors in the dropdown form without reloading the page. I can only print them on the checkuser.php page.

Comment: Why not echo `$errors` wrapped in a PHP tag at the place of choice? Have you tried something similar?

Comment: But if I only use PHP the page will always refresh whenever I click the submit button? So I guess I have to make use of AJAX?

Comment: I'm not too savvy with AJAX myself, yet it does sound like a worthy option.

Comment: On to my search for an AJAX God I guess :)

Comment: Or find a working script on Google. Chances are, you'll end up finding something here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution:

Here's my Jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".bt_login").click(function(){
        email = $("#email").val();
        password = $("#password").val();
        if(email == '' || password == ''){
            $(".errors").html("Please fill in both fields!");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkuser.php",
            data: "email=" + email + "&password=" + password,
            success: function(html){
                if(html == 'true'){
                    window.location = "index.php";
                } else {
                    $(".errors").html("Wrong username or password!");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and my checkuser.php:

```
<?php

include "core/init.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if( $num_row >=1 ) {
    echo 'true';
$_SESSION['userID']=$row['userID'];
$_SESSION['last_name']=$row['last_name'];
$_SESSION['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
}
else{
echo 'false';
}

?>
```

Although it may not be the safest solution, it works for now :) Will try to build in more security later.